# How do I execute a batch file in an alternate data stream in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, batch, alternate-data-stream

Normally, after creating an executable as an alternate data stream, for instance:

```
type exec_this.bat > C:\blank.txt:exe.bat
```

one could simply say

```
start C:\blank.txt:exe.bat
```

to run the executable. In Windows 7, all I seem to get is "Access is denied." or "The system cannot find the file $WHATEVER_THE_FILE_IS."

**How can I execute this batch file?**

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  What's your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/284737/680651) only runs one line of the batch file at a time. This will interrupt any advanced logic in the batch file. But, if you use a temporary file you can do this in a one-liner:

```
cat < blank.txt:exe.bat > temp.bat & temp.bat
```

You can also execute a PowerShell script in an alternate data stream via a similar command: (Though I am sure there is a pure PowerShell way too.)

```
cat < blank.txt:exe.ps1 > temp.ps1 & powershell .\temp.ps1
```

### Example

Create batch in the alternate data stream: `notepad blank.txt:exe.bat`

```
if 6==7 then goto pie 
echo apple 
goto end 
:pie 
echo pie 
:end
```

Broken:

```sh
E:\broken>for /f "usebackq delims=φ" %i in (blank.txt:exe.bat) do %i

E:\broken>if 6==7 then goto pie
'if' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\broken>echo apple
apple

E:\broken>goto end

E:\broken>
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

E:\broken>echo pie
pie

E:\broken>
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Better:

```sh
E:\better>cat < blank.txt:exe.bat > temp.bat & temp.bat

E:\better>if 6 == 7 then goto pie

E:\better>echo apple
apple

E:\better>goto end
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 silently removed the ability to execute **anything** from an ADS. However, from the DOS command line, there are other options. For a batch file, you can execute line by line:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=φ" %i in (blank.txt:exe.bat) do %i
```

(Keep in mind, this does not actually execute the batch file into its own process, it simply reads and executes each line from the file. The `φ` symbol is typed with [alt code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) number 2541. You want the delimiter to be a character you wouldn't ever use in the code.)